# Accelerate an animation on a fixed path

Tags: css, animation

I have the following code that animates a ball along a the path of a sin wave:

```css
.ball {
  animation: animX 5s infinite linear;
}

.ball::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  animation: animY 5s infinite;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content:'';
  display: block;
}

@keyframes animX {
  0% {
   transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
   transform: translateX(125px);
  }
  75% {
   transform: translateX(375px);
  }
  100% {
   transform: translateX(500px);
  }
}

@keyframes animY {
  0% {
   transform: translateY(0px);
   animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
   transform: translateY(-50px);
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  75% {
   transform: translateY(50px);
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  100% {
   transform: translateY(0px);
   animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"/>
```

I'm trying to add two more things in this animation, that only apply over the last 25% of the animation:

1. The circle should accelerate out to twice the starting speed, along
   the same path.
2. The circle should scale down to 30% of the original size

For 1. I've tried changing the `animation-timing-function` of the last stage of the animation, but it seems to distort the path of the circle, which I do not want.  For 2. I've tried adding in `scale(0.3)` to the `transform` rule, but that also seems to mess up the path of the ball. Is there some trick I need to do to make these things happen independently of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first one

```css
/* Styles go here */

.ball {
  animation: animX 5s infinite linear;
}

.ball::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  animation: animY 5s infinite;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content:'';
  display: block;
}

@keyframes animX {
  0% {
   transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
   transform: translateX(125px);
  }
  75% {
   transform: translateX(375px);
  }
  80% {
   transform: translateX(400px);
  }
  85% {
   transform: translateX(405px);
  }
  90% {
   transform: translateX(425px);
  }
  95% {
   transform: translateX(555px);
  }
  100% {
   transform: translateX(600px);
  }
}

@keyframes animY {
  0% {
   transform: translateY(0px);
   animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
   transform: translateY(-50px);
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  75% {
   transform: translateY(50px);
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  100% {
   transform: translateY(0px);
   transform:scale(0.3);
   animation-timing-function:  cubic-bezier(.92,.02,.74,1.03);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <div class="ball"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Add transform:scale(0.3);

```
100% {
   transform: translateY(0px);
   transform:scale(0.3);
   animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
```

About second one I think you need to play with cubic-bezier timing function
http://cubic-bezier.com/

Comment: The bezier curve still doesn't gives the "accelerating out" effect I'm looking for though. Changing the timing function changes the path of the circle, not the speed which I'm looking for.

Comment: You should add more keyframes to change speed, add more keyframes for translateX. That would change the speed for the ball.

Comment: I changed my answer and added some keyframes, just play around so you can figure out how fast you want it to move, hope it helps